# how can i select one date in a calendar that cannot be selected by any other patient using php database?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am setting up a date and time calendar in the phpmyadmin database to select an appointment date by the patients but once one date is selected it can not be selected again. How can I do this in phphmyadmin and connect it with the database?

```
         <h5> Date: </h5>
           <input type="datetime-local"/><br>
         </form>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table with valid options. Let's say you can have patients between 9.00 am and 5.00 pm. A patient can book 30 mins appointments, therefore you need 30 mins intervals.

I'd call my table `PossibleAppointments`:

```
=================
=  id  =  time  =
=================
-   1  -  9:00  -
-----------------
-   2  -  9:30  -
-----------------
-      ...      -
-----------------
-   #  -  4:30  -
-----------------
```

Add another table called `BookedAppointments`, where you have an entry, such as:

```
================================
=  id  =      date    =  time  =
================================
-   #  -  2019-04-22  -    2   -
--------------------------------
```

Note that the column `time` would represent the id of one row of `PossibleAppointments`.

Now, whenever a patient wants to book an appointment, display a dropdown `input` and filter out already booked appointments based on your tables.

Comment: Will, I made these tables in phpmyadmin? I have other things also created on that page(website) like you can select specialty and doctor NAME gender and with the patient's name including this DateTime form will this still work.

Comment: How can I write the code of connection with these tables?